# When setting a FormatCondition on a range which is not selected, this fails?

Tags: excel, format, excel-2007, conditional-statements, vba

I've this VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Sheet1.Cells(10, 10).Select

    Range("$B$2:$E$7").FormatConditions.Delete
    With Range("$B$2:$E$7").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$G2=""Yes""")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 0)
    End With
    Debug.Print "Formula is wrong   : " & Range("$B$2:$E$7").FormatConditions(1).Formula1

    Range("$B$2:$E$7").Select
    Range("$B$2:$E$7").FormatConditions.Delete
    With Range("rngDatesLockedRange").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$G2=""Yes""")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(150, 100, 0)
    End With
    Debug.Print "Formula is correct : " & Range("$B$2:$E$7").FormatConditions(1).Formula1
End Sub
```

The debug tracing shows:

```
Formula is wrong   : =$G1048570="Yes"
Formula is correct : =$G2="Yes"
```

Why does it not work when you don't select the range before applying formatting to that range?
In Excel 2010, this works fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has [a kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895562)! on this exact issue.

It seems to confirm the problem, but suggests using absolute references or selecting cells as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional formatting in Excel (at least in 2007) will make the rule relative to the **Starting Location** of the formatting rule and **Your Current Selection**.  Note this does **not** happen if you use the absolute `$` reference character.

Let me explain what is happening in your specific situation:

Right away your macro selects cells `10,10` i.e `J10`.  Now you are using the formula `=$G2="YES"` and since you have the absolute reference for the column `$G` the column will never change. However the row will change relative to where the condition starts (i.e. `B2`).  Well `10-2=8` so it will **move the row up 8 spaces** since you start at row `2` it will overflow by `8-2=6` spaces.  There are `1048576` rows in Excel 2007 and thus you are seeing `1048570` because `1048576 - 6 = 1048570`.  Resulting in your final formula of `=$G1048570="YES"`

Once you select the range you are using the conditional formatting on, the row never changes because you are on the same row.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Stef does that answer your question?  If something is still unclear or if it doesnt answer it completely let me know

Comment: It does explain how Excel is working. It does not explain why this works fine on Excel 2010 , and not in Excel 2007. The other answer given confirm that this is a bug in Excel 2007, so I'll have to use that workaround because my Excel sheet needs to be working for both 2007 and 2010.